# Backcolor change of radiobutton, with button appearance

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm creating a laboratory application in VS2013, where the user enters a rack number, and gets back a visual grid of which samples he/she has to weigh for a certain analysis, for that specific rack with samples.

I'm getting the information from an Oracle DB, based on the requested/send SQL string.

I've created radio buttons as a means of selecting/filter the analysis type.
I've given them the appearance of regular buttons, in the object properties.

When a certain radio buttons is clicked, I want to give them a specific color, depending on the type of analysis.
The same color will be used to mark the samples that are to be weighed in the visual grid.

When I test the program, the radio buttons do what they need to do (meaning: getting the correct info from Oracle DB), but I can't seem to manage the backcolor change of the radio buttons.
The backcolor change of the regular buttons (on visual grid) is working correctly.

I trigger the function behind all this, by Function Rbanalysistype (sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles *Rbanalysistype1*.Click, *Rbanalysistype2*.Click, ...

```
Public Function RbAnaTypeClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RbAnaTypeAcIn.CheckedChanged
    Dim SenderName As String = ""
    Dim TitrType As String = ""

    SenderName = CType(sender, RadioButton).Name

    Select Case SenderName

        Case Is = "RbAnaTypeAcIn"
            TitrType = "AcIn"

            'put correct Radiobuttion in GbAnaType in color
            If RbAnaTypeAcIn.Checked = True Then
                RbAnaTypeAcIn.BackColor = Color.Orange
            End If

    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: so ill just go ahead and say it, im sure that among the millions of users on stack overflow, there is at least one who knows what you are talking about by heart. but most of us, are just trying to assist even if we are not familiar with what you are doing specifically and can really help you with the code if we actually see it. but if you are going to just write a block of text without snippets to support it, there is really not much we can do. and as you can see, 7 people read your question yet only i commented. guess why.

Comment: Banana, I'm new to this site and not yet fully accustomed to how to post question. I can understand what you are saying and why, but let me be blunt: there are other ways of saying what you are saying.

Comment: As stated in my profile, I'm a chemist doing some programming work for our lab. I only have minor experience in programming and thus it's a bit more difficult for me to know how to formulate my questions in the right manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're handling the wrong event for a start.  Here's the sort of thing you should be doing:

```
Private Sub RadioButtons_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged,
                                                                                  RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    Dim rb = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)

    If rb.Checked Then
        rb.BackColor = Color.Red
    Else
        rb.BackColor = Color.Green
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. at first it didn't work.
But after some further digging, I found in another section of the code that the Flatstyle of the Radiobutton was set on "System" in stead of "Standard".
With the "System" property, you can't change the backcolor.
I've set it on "Standard" now and it works perfectly.